# Research paper for paired t-test implemented in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-test

I have used paired t-test to validate the hypothesis using my data from R. Is there any research article related to t-test in R?

If there is any article related to t-test in R, please let me know.

Comment: I think this is more related to [http://stats.stackexchange.com/](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

A good place to look in general for citations is the documentation of the function. In this case however, a paired t-test is so basic that you can simply refer to an introductory statistics book that describes the test.

Comment: Thanks, I already thought that too. However, I have used it from R. It is better to cite form R if available.

Comment: The t-test in R is simply the standard implementation of the t-test, so there is no specific need to cite R. I sometimes have added to a paper of mine that I did the analyses in R. But this was more of a remark in the Acknowledgements section.

Comment: I always state (with the reference `citation()` asks for) in my Methods section that a specific R version was used.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Paul that for the paired t-test with a pooled SD (mean of pretest SD and posttest SD), you don't necessarily need a citation.
Nevertheless, there are more sophisticated methods like raw score standardization or change score standardization, e.g. implemented by the `metafor` package.

So for what it's worth, here are some related references.

Morris, Scott B. 2008. “Estimating Effect Sizes From Pretest-Posttest-Control Group Designs.” Organizational Research Methods 11 (2): 364–86.
Davis, John M. 1993. “Experiments Involving Paired Comparisons” 18 (3): 271–79.

Fritz, Catherine O., Peter E. Morris, and Jennifer J. Richler. 2012. “Effect Size Estimates: Current Use, Calculations, and Interpretation.” Journal of Experimental Psychology: General 141 (1): 2–18. https://doi.org/10.1037/a0024338.

Lakens, Daniël. 2013. “Calculating and Reporting Effect Sizes to Facilitate Cumulative Science: A Practical Primer for t-Tests and ANOVAs.” Frontiers in Psychology 4 (NOV): 1–12. https://doi.org/10.3389/fpsyg.2013.00863.

Morris, Scott B., and Richard P. DeShon. 2002. “Combining Effect Size Estimates in Meta-Analysis with Repeated Measures and Independent-Groups Designs.” Psychological Methods 7 (1): 105–25. https://doi.org/10.1037/1082-989X.7.1.105.

O’Brien, Fearghal, and Denis Cousineau. 2015. “Representing Error Bars in Within-Subject Designs in Typical Software Packages.” The Quantitative Methods for Psychology 11 (2): 126–126. https://doi.org/10.20982/tqmp.11.2.p126.

Cousineau, Denis. 2005. “Confidence Intervals in Within-Subject Designs: A Simpler Solution to Loftus and Masson’s Method.” Tutorials in Quantitative Methods for Psychology 1 (1): 42–45.